# Remainder when divided by $7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What would be the remainder when
$12^1 +  12^2 + 12^3 +\cdots + 12^{100}$ is divided by $7$ ?

I tried cyclic approach (pattern method), but I couldn't solve this particular question.

Comment: i tried  euler method also but couldnt unfortunately i would have to do with every term . Could you please help me out?

Comment: What did you get for $12^k\bmod 7$ for $k=1,2,\ldots ,7$? In particular, what is $12^7\bmod 7$? It becomes cyclic...

Comment: 5 , 4,6 ,2 ,3 , 1.. This is the cycle i get for k=1,2,3,4,5,6...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments, you recognized that $12^1+12^2+12^3+\cdots+12^{100}$

$\equiv \underbrace{5+4+6+2+3+1}+\underbrace{5+4+6+2+3+1}+\underbrace{5+4+6+2+3+1}+\underbrace{5+4+6+2+3+1}+\underbrace{5+4+6+2+3+1}+\underbrace{5+4+6+2+3+1}+\underbrace{5+4+6+2+3+1}+\underbrace{5+4+6+2+3+1}+\underbrace{5+4+6+2+3+1}+\underbrace{5+4+6+2+3+1}+\underbrace{5+4+6+2+3+1}+\underbrace{5+4+6+2+3+1}+\underbrace{5+4+6+2+3+1}+\underbrace{5+4+6+2+3+1}+\underbrace{5+4+6+2+3+1}+\underbrace{5+4+6+2+3+1}+\,5+4+6+2\pmod7.$

Note that the sum over each brace is a multiple of $7$, and you're almost done.

Answer (score 3):

This is a geometric series, which can be simplified to
$$12^1+12^2+\cdots+12^{100}=\frac{12}{11}(12^{100}-1)$$

Since $\gcd(12,7)=1$, Euler's Totient theorem applies. Can you take it from here?

Comment: it should be( 12^101    - 1  /   11)

Comment: No, $a+ar+ar^2+\cdots+ar^{n-1}=a\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$ with $a=12$, $n=100$ and $r=12$ gives $\frac{12}{11}(12^{100}-1)$

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$1+\sum_{i=1}^{100}12^i=\frac{12^{101}-1}{12-1}=\frac{12^{101}-1}{11}$$

Since $\gcd(7,11)=1$, we need only find the remainer of $12^{101}-1$ with $7$.

We have $12^{101}\equiv 5^{101}\bmod 7$ and $5^{101}=25^{50}\cdot5\equiv 5\mod7$

Thus $12^{101}-1\equiv 4\mod7$
and as we explained this gives $\frac{12^{101}-1}{11}\equiv4\mod7$
So $\sum_{i=1}^{100}12^i\equiv 3\mod7$.

Answer (score 1):

As $12\equiv-2\pmod7, 12^3\equiv(-2)^3\equiv-8\equiv-1,$ord$_712=6$

$\implies12^{6k+r}\equiv12^r\equiv(-2)^r\pmod7$

$$\sum_{r=1}^{100}12^r\equiv12^1+12^2+12^3+12^4+16\sum_{r=0}^512^r\pmod7$$

$$\equiv(-2)+(-2)^2+(-2)^3+(-2)^4+2\sum_{r=0}^5(-2)^r\pmod7$$

Finally $\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^5(-2)^r\equiv\dfrac{(-2)^6-1}{-2-1}\equiv0\pmod7$ as $(-2-1,7)=1$

Answer (score 0):

Fun Fact: $12= -2,2^{3k}= 1, 2^{3k+1}=2, 2^{3k+2}=4$ in $\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z$. Thus, $$\sum_{i=1}^{100}12^i\equiv \sum_{i=1}^{100}(-2)^i\equiv -2^{0}+2^{99}+2^{100}+\sum_{a=0}^{32}(-2)^{3a}+(-2)^{3a+1}+(-2)^{3a+2}\pmod{7}$$
Now trivial right?